# c++ sizeof(array) return twice the array's declared length

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have a section of code in which two array are declared with sizes of 6 and 13, but when 'sizeof()' is used the lengths are returned as 12 and 26.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    enum charRaces {DWARF,ELF,GNOME,HALFELF,HALFLING,HUMAN};
    enum classes{WARRIOR,FIGHTER,RANGER,PALADIN,WIZARD,MAGE,ILLUSIONIST,PRIEST,CLERIC,DRUID,ROGUE,THEIF,BARD};

    short int races[6] = {DWARF,ELF,GNOME,HALFELF,HALFLING,HUMAN};
    short int classes[13] = {WARRIOR,FIGHTER,RANGER,PALADIN,WIZARD,MAGE,ILLUSIONIST,PRIEST,CLERIC,DRUID,ROGUE,THEIF,BARD};

    cout << "sizeof(races)\t"  << sizeof(races) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(classes)\t"  << sizeof(classes) << endl;

    system("pause");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: After you take everyone's advice below and use `sizeof(array_var)/sizeof(array_var[0])` remember it does NOT work when you replace the array_var with a pointer_var. If that sounded confusing to you I suggest you read more on arrays, pointers, and the distinguised differences between them.

Comment: Look at what you are doing: You are declaring two arrays one with 6 items and one with 13 items. You then call sizeof on these arrays, which, predictably, returns the number of elements in the arrays multiplied by the size of each element. 

Since you declared your arrays as `short int` which, on your platform, are 16-bits (or 2 bytes) each, the compiler correctly returns 12 (or 2 * 6) and 26 (or 2 * 13) bytes for races and classes respectively.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof` returns the size of a variable (in this case, your arrays), where `sizeof(char)` is 1. Since a `char` is one byte wide, `sizeof` returns the size of the variable in bytes. Since each `short int` is two bytes wide on your system, an array of 6 of them will have size 12, and an array of 13 will have size 26.

Comment: True, though in this case "byte" only means "8 bits" when an unsigned char is 8 bits long.

Comment: is there a method if returning the size of an array then?

Comment: `sizeof` _always_ returns the number of bytes if the C++ implementation conforms to the Standard. See §5.3.3. This has nothing to do with how many bits there are in a byte.

Comment: @DyP I thought the standard specified that a `char` was _at least_ a byte wide, though I've never seen a system where it was larger.

Comment: @slavik262 In C everything is defined in terms of `sizeof(char)`, which is by definition 1. If chars are larger than 1 byte you'd have a platform where there is no type small enough to represent 1 byte. This would be legal but bizarre.

Comment: The number of bits in an unsigned char is specified by CHAR_BIT from limits.h. sizeof (unsigned char) will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: @BrookJulias see John Kugelman's answer. A possibly better solution would be to use a `std::vector`, in which case you can just use `vector::size()`

Comment: @slavik262, John Kugelman: `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 in §5.3.3. A byte is at least 8 bits wide in C++11 (§1.7).

Comment: @JohnKugelman It wouldn't be legal; as DyP says, C++ defines sizeof to return size "in bytes" (for C++'s own definition of bytes) and `sizeof(char)` to be 1. Of course it's possible that the byte as defined by C++ might not be a byte as the hardware engineer for a given platform would think of it.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` returns the size in bytes, which for an array is the number of items × the size of each item. To get the number of items divide by the size of one element.

```
sizeof(races) / sizeof(races[0])
```

Be careful with this. It will only work for arrays whose size is known at compile time. This will not work:

```
void func(short int array[])
{
    // DOES NOT WORK
    size_t size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

Here `array` is actually a `short int *` and `sizeof(array)` does not return the actual size of the array, which is unknown at compile time.

This is one of many reasons to prefer [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) or [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/) to raw arrays in C++.

Comment: Under what circumstance would this ever be used? If you're allocating a non-fixed size array, you would know (or at some point calculate) the number of members. Better yet, you could use a `vector`.

Comment: @slavik262 If you have a constant array somewhere, this kind of code would keep you from having to update the array and the count of items separately.

Comment: You could also use a `std::array`.

Comment: If you have a constant array, you know its size without having to resort to division like this (even though it would probably be resolved at compile time). I'm not disputing that this works, but it just seems like a needless obfuscation.

Comment: @slavik262 Yeah, you know the size. Without the division though, you have to remember to update both the array and the size field when something changes.

Comment: @slavik262 The OP could leave out the explicit `6` and `13` and this trick would still work.

Comment: Adding to what @JohnKugelman said: It's a reasonably common C idiom to create an array whose size is implicit in its initializer, and then get its size as `#define FOO_SIZE (sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]))`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the actual memory in bytes used by the array. A fairly common idiom is to do something like this:

```
short int races[6] = {DWARF,ELF,GNOME,HALFELF,HALFLING,HUMAN};
size_t num_races = sizeof(races) / sizeof(races[0]);
```

`num_races` would then have the number of elements in the array stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof operator is measured in units such that an unsigned char is 1 unit.

On your platform, short is twice as large as char, thus the results you're seeing.

To properly determine array length, you could use a macro such as:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(ary) (sizeof (ary) / sizeof (ary[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

sizeof is an operator in C++ that measure the size in number of bytes.I think in your machine integer take 2 bytes that's why It's displaying the double the size of the array.

Comment: Its displaying 2x because he's using arrays of unsigned **short** integers, which on his platform are 16-bits wide. The machine integer on his platform is likely 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes required to represent the type (at compile time).

```
double array[10]; // type of array is: double[10]
```

`sizeof(array)` has the same meaning as `sizeof(double[10])`, which is equal to:

```
sizeof(double) * 10
```

It's an array that can hold 10 double values. `sizeof(array[0])` means: size of a single element in array, which is the same as `sizeof(double)` here. To get the actual number of elements, you have to divide the size of the array by the size of a single element:

```
size_t num_elem = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

However, this doesn't work on pointers!

```
double* p = array;
```

`sizeof(p)` actually translates to `sizeof(double*)`. Its size has nothing to do with the size of double or the size of the array it's pointing to.
Instead, it's the size required to store the address to a memory location (32 bits on a 32bit operating). The information about the number of elements is lost!

If you want to safely get the number of elements in an array, you can use this template:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t inline static_arrlen(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;
}
```

At compile-time, it deduces the type T and number of elements N, returning N.

```
size_t num_elem = static_arrlen(array); // T=double, N=10
```

If you're trying to get the array size from a pointer, it won't compile:

```
static_arrlen(p); // ERROR: could not deduce template argument 
                  // for 'T (&)[N]' from 'double *'
```