# All combinatations algorithm and general approach to solving C++ problems

Tags: c++

Does anyone here ever feel they are way over their depth with regard to C++, well beginners, yes I can work my way through C++ in 21 days, the OO chapters are ok in small proportions. I did learn VB6 as a hobby on and off for a couple of years a few years ago, but the problem obviously arises when you start getting into any codebase larger than tiny tbh. The larger the codebase the OO aspect becomes pretty daunting trying to keep in touch of what you are actually doing.

The other problem, which I learned in VB6(to a lesser degree) is the fact that there are always multiple ways of solving a problem/algorithm, the key point is efficiency(speed + bug free code). Hacking together solutions in code is one thing, writing sophisticated, high quality, intelligent, efficient code for larger codebases is a totally different beast. Maybe I should try c#/VB instead?

Take a basic problem for example.

1. Write an algorithm that outputs every combination for a given set of characters up to N combinations. Say [0-9][N=3] so
   000
   001
   002
   ...
   111
   112
   113
   ...
   999

Not unique perms but all combs.

As I said there must be quite a few ways to do this, raw C and C++ style with char arrays, pointers and recursion, or using some functionality from the SL or STL libraries such as dynamic arrays/Vectors/Maps or Templates and any other goodies that are available in the SL/STL such as next_permutation etc.

Apart from the fact that even a C style algo for this problem using array(s) can be a mind twister in itself, you then have the added headache as to whether to use other library functions or not Which is the most efficient way to solve this problem.

This is my very hacky attempt, first I do not use pointers and second I couldn't implement the N combinations without having to use multiple messy for/switch loops.

So I have hardcoded this for [0-9] and for 3 combos of this set, now it does work to a degree, however at the end it weirdly steps over the conditions(apparently) set and adds another 10 rows of combinations. In this case 'j' to 10 where j=10 is NULL in the array and hence the NULL space as shown here. You will see if you run the program.
 00
 01
 02
 03
 04
 05
 06
 07
 08
 09

Also I have used global variables I guess I should really be using pointers instead?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
void recurse_array(int N, char c_arr[]);

int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int i = 0;
ofstream myfile;

int main()
{
    int N;
    myfile.open("data.txt");
    cout << "Enter number N combos ";
    cin >> N;
    char c_arr[11] = "0123456789";
    recurse_array(N, c_arr);
}

void recurse_array(int N, char c_arr[])
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Why does sizeof not work when array is passed to function
        myfile << c_arr[j] << c_arr[k] << c_arr[i] << endl; //Expand << c_arr[x] to N times ??
    }
    while ((j < 10)) { // Why does j still = 10 at end for 10 more rows.
        if ((k == 9) && (i == 10)) { // why is i 10 and not 9????
            k = 0;
            j++;
            recurse_array(N, c_arr);
        } else {
            k++;
            recurse_array(N, c_arr);
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see this is hardwired only for 3 combos, after that I would have to completely redo the code to add more combos. I just can't see how to generify this. I am sure it's a simple(ish) elegant solution. Are some people born to become C++'ers, I take it design and methodology is half the battle when writing code. Pratice obvioulsy plays a bit.....

Any tips for how to approach problems and also the best way to solve this particular algorithm above.

Comment: For me you C++ code looks more like C code with "let's put a bit of cpp features here and there". Also, since C++ is a multi-paradigm language I don't think there is ONE viable answer... And generally "good practices" change with each revision of the C++ standard, i.e. good C++11 might be very bad C++98...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201016/c-sizeofarray-return-twice-the-arrays-declared-length/13201043#13201043

Comment: "well beginners, yes I can work my way through C++ in 21 days" C++ is not something that you learn in 21 days. I have programmed professionally for 17+ years in the process I have written over 1 million lines of c++ code and I still have much to learn..

Answer (score 1):

I would do that way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool increment(std::vector<int>& v, int maxSize)
{
    for (auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) {
        ++*it;
        if (*it != maxSize) {
            return true;
        }
        *it = 0;
    }
    return false;
}

template <int N>
void display(const std::vector<int>& v, const char (&digits)[N])
{
    for (auto elem : v) {
        std::cout << digits[elem];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template <int N>
void display_combinaison(int count, const char (&digits)[N])
{
    std::vector<int> v(count);

    do {
        display(v, digits);
    } while (increment(v, N - 1));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    display_combinaison(3, "0123456789");

    return 0;
}
```

> Why does sizeof not work when array is passed to function

In `void function(int a[11])`, size `11` is ignored
and it decays to `void function(int* a)`
so `sizeof(a) == sizeof(int*)`

The way to pass fixed size array is

```
void function(int (&a)[11])
```

And so `sizeof(a) == 11 * sizeof(int)`. (care that `sizeof(int) != 1`)
so `11 == sizeof(a) == sizeof(*a)`

to be generic, you may use template:

```
template <int N>
void function(int (&a)[N])
```

So, it can take any fixed size array.
Note that we have N, so no need to use `sizeof(a)`

But, the simplest way is to have `void function(int* a, unsigned int size)`

Answer (score 0):

> Why does sizeof not work when array is passed to function

[c++ sizeof(array) return twice the array's declared length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201016/c-sizeofarray-return-twice-the-arrays-declared-length/13201043#13201043)

> Why does j still = 10 at end for 10 more rows.

You declared j as a global and initialized it to 0 then you increment it only when it is less than 10. After the first 10 rows it will be 10 and stay at 10 since you do not change it. Perhaps you wanted j to be a local variable in recurse_array.

> why is i 10 and not 9????

Your for loop loops while i < 10.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Why does sizeof not work when array is passed to function
    myfile << c_arr[j] << c_arr[k] << c_arr[i] << endl; //Expand << c_arr[x] to N times ??
}
```

After the loop completed i would have to be at least 10 to exit the loop.